# To add crystal report viewer to application exe's prerequsites

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have created a windows application using c# which uses CrystalReport to view daily reports.The problem  is I want the user to view report in the client machine without downloading crystal report.so how can I add crystal report viewer to application exe's prerequisites,so that the exe in the client machine automatically downloads crystal report from the application.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use ClickOnce or Setup Project?

Comment: setup project.which one to use??

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following options

1. Create a Setup Project and add the Crystal Reports as a prerequisite. This will force a download during the installation. Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi) for more information on how to create a Setup Project and how to add prerequisites.
2. Download the Crystal Reports runtime (msi file) from [this link](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) and deploy it in a folder of your application. Create a function that will check the existence of the crystal reports assemblies when the application starts. If the assemblies are missing it's either the first time that the application runs or someone has uninstalled the crystal reports runtime from the machine. In either case install the runtime file from the local folder.

These options have their pros and cons

In the first case, the client's machine has to have an internet connection so it can download the prerequisite but the package size will be small since you don't deploy all the files locally and you don't have to care about the type of package 32bit/64bit that will be downloaded based on the client's machine.

In the second case you don't need an internet connection (except if you need it for some other operations) but the package size will be greatly increased since each crystal reports runtime is around 80MB and double that size if you will deploy both 32bit/64bit versions.

Comment: thank you,Will check how it works and get back to you